# How do I send an email to all event participants immediately?

Tags: civievent, civimail

I know you can schedule reminders, but you can't choose a date and time, only a date (when does it send if you choose the same day?), otherwise you have to choose a time before the event or after the event.

I just want to send an email right now and I don't want to have to create a group to do it.
This is a basic feature in competing platforms - is there something obvious i am missing?

Comment: it might help clarify the issue if you explain if the goal is a/ i just want to email all existing participants of the event 'now', or b/ i want to email participants immediately they register. I can see both interpretations to the Subject

Comment: You're getting comments both for, "I want to send an email automatically as people register" and "I want to send an email to all registered participants."  Could you please clarify which is intended?

Answer (score 3):

If your event has more than 50 participants, then you could install the 'Transactional Email' extension, (nz.co.fuzion.transactional), which allows you to send emails using CiviMail to search results. We use this for many purposes.

It has really helped us to be able to send an email to event participants/members, using the full capabilities of CiviMail - draft emails, result tracking, spam protection, etc etc.

If people have booked on an event or a membership with your organisation then European GDPR rules allow you to email them, since they are deemed to be interested in you. (Providing, of course, that your email is actually about what they booked! :-) ).

Comment: hmm. i had totally forgotten about that capability

Answer (score 2):

Can you create a activity reminder of type event registration and send the reminder after 0 hour of activity date time?

[image]

Comment: I think that would work - but event sign up does not appear as an option. Also - I assume I would have to disable it after completing if we are going to send other emails.

Comment: there should be an activity of type event registration which you can use. Its created after user registers for an event

Comment: When I try to create a schedule reminder, I do not see Entity option..

Comment: The above screenshot is taken from dmaster(https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders?action=add&reset=1),  do you have any custom extension that hides the entity option?

Comment: This is what I see - Drupal 7, Civi 5.28.2 https://imgur.com/a/vllYnk2

Comment: i guess your site must have some customization

Comment: I also see the same screen as themak. Maybe the option you are showing @PradeepNayak is something introduced in 5.29?

Comment: Is themak looking at the Sch Reminder tab in Events, where as Pradeep is looking at Sch Reminders via Admin > Comms perhaps?

Comment: That is what is happening - not helpful when you have users that you don't want having access to admin items. Also you can't choose the event using that activity.

Comment: can you limit that Activity based on a Smart Group of participants for 'that' event. More effort but technically 'can' be done I think

Answer (score 0):

You can go to where you see your event participants list, select the participants, click Actions and click Email - send now(to 50 or less).

Obviously you can only use this option properly if the number of participants is less than 50.

[image]

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately there are a few hundred participants.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a smart group of all participants, and then send a mailing to the group members.

Comment: i think his goal is the information is sent out as soon as some registers for the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set this up via CiviRules where the Trigger is 'registration activity' and the filters are for Event X and the Action is 'send email' (needs email api extension as well as civirules)